# How to properly load different set of CSS file in different route in Vuejs project

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, vue.js, layout

I'm currently building a vuejs + laravel project, it will have very different layout for admin/user panel and landing page, so i need to load different CSS file for different route.

Currently i'm using vanilla js to determine whether which CSS file to load in different route, i want to know is there any proper way or proper method to do this?

Here is my current approach:
In every route there will be an array of CSS files that need to be load, if the CSS file already loaded, the script will ignore, if not, will append a `<link>` to load CSS, if the CSS file is not required anymore, it will be disable, if the CSS file already included but disabled, it will be enable back.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

  // load styles
  if (to.meta.styles) {
    to.meta.styles.forEach((item, i) => {
      let element = document.querySelector(`[rel="stylesheet"][href="${item}"][class="appStyles"]`);

      if (!element) {
        var link = document.createElement( "link" );
        link.href = item;
        link.type = "text/css";
        link.rel = "stylesheet";
        link.setAttribute("class", "appStyles");
        document.getElementsByTagName( "head" )[0].appendChild( link );
      }
    });
  }

  // disable styles
  let existingStyleSheet = document.querySelectorAll(`[rel="stylesheet"][class="appStyles"]`);
  if (existingStyleSheet) {
    // console.log(to.meta.styles);
    existingStyleSheet.forEach((item, i) => {
      if (to.meta.styles) {
        let needed = 0;
        to.meta.styles.forEach((stylesheet, i) => {
          if (item.href == stylesheet) {
            needed += 1;
          }
        });

        // console.log(needed);

        item.disabled = false
        if (needed == 0) {
          item.disabled = true
          item.parentNode.removeChild(item)
        }
      }
    });
  }

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to load a single css file the normal way (inside header tags) and to pass a specific class to the body tag according to the layout/page. Hope you got the idea.. Ture that there will be a bit of unwanted styling but this will reduce the complexity and will enable easy code maintenance. Here's an example:

```
 $h2-orange: #f60;
 $h2-green: #0f0;

 /*common styles - maintains consistancy */
 .h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    
 }

 /* Theme 1 specifics */
 .orange-theme {
     .h2 {
         color: $h2-blue;
      }
      /* other specific styles for Theme 1 */
 }

 /* Theme 2 specifics */
 .green-theme {
     .h2 {
         color: $h2-green;
      }
      /* other specific styles for Theme 2 */
 }
```